# Activity within the tabs in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, tabs

this is my login view https://i.stack.imgur.com/kO1cT.jpg  , a successful login will redirect to this page https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FPll.jpg
but, instead of launch a new intent, I want the activity is proceed within the tab.
This is how I describe it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKY8x.jpg 
(Note: The last pic is just an edited photoshop in order to give you a sample of what I want it to be). Sorry for asking newbie question, I appreciate your help thanks before.

This is my code :
Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends Activity {
    String var_usr,var_pass;
    EditText usr, psw;
    JSONArray str_login = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.panel_login);

        usr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        psw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_pass);


        Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                var_usr = usr.getText().toString();
                var_pass = psw.getText().toString();
                String stts = "";
                String kode = "";
                String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/gollege/login.php?usr="+var_usr+"&psw="+var_pass;
                com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.JSONParser jParser = new com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

                try {
                    str_login = json.getJSONArray("statuslogin");

                    for(int i = 0; i < str_login.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject ar = str_login.getJSONObject(i);
                        TextView st = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_alert);
                        String alrt = ar.getString("hasil");
                        stts = ar.getString("st");
                        kode = ar.getString("id");
                        st.setText(alrt);
                        usr.setText("");
                        psw.setText("");

                        if(stts.trim().equals("ok"))
                        {
                            Intent ni = null;                           
                            ni = new Intent(Tab1.this, com.bucheuw.gollege.portal.DashboardActivity.class);
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();
                            b.putString("par_kode", kode);
                            ni.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(ni);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

DashboardAcitvity.java

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {

    public String nim;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.panel_dashboard);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        nim = b.getString("par_kode");

        Button btn_datapribadi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_datapribadi);
        Button btn_ksm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ksm);
        Button btn_jdwlkuliah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_jdwlkuliah);
        Button btn_absensi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_absensi);
        Button btn_nilai = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nilai);
        Button btn_tak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tak);
        Button btn_ips = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ips);
        Button btn_jdwlujian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_jdwlujian);
        Button btn_pengumuman = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pengumuman);
        Button btn_klndr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_klndr);
        Button btn_logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);

        btn_datapribadi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DataPribadiActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_ksm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KSMActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_jdwlkuliah.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JadwalKuliahActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_absensi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AbsensiActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_nilai.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NilaiActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_tak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TAKActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

       btn_ips.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IPSActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_jdwlujian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JadwalUjianActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_pengumuman.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InfoKampusActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_klndr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {                        
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), KalenderAkademikActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {    
                    Intent exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    DashboardActivity.this.finish();

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the parent activity class where the tabhost is created I implemented a method like the one below:

```
public void switchTab(int tab){
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
}
```

Inside of the tab that I would like to be able to switch internally to another tab I created the method below:

```
public void switchTabInActivity(int indexTabToSwitchTo){
            MintTrack ParentActivity;
            ParentActivity = (MintTrack) this.getParent();
            ParentActivity.switchTab(indexTabToSwitchTo);
}
```

If you would like a good example of this code, you can take a look at my MintTrack project [here](http://code.google.com/p/minttrack/source/browse/branches/MintTrackV2/MintTrack/src/com/ponyinc/minttrack/MintTrack.java) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/minttrack/source/browse/branches/MintTrackV2/MintTrack/src/com/ponyinc/minttrack/tabs/AuditActivity.java).

As a side note, please be very careful when deciding whether to use view or activity based TabHost.

Activity based tabs are great because they can be separated into there own XML file. Activities can also be organized into there own Java file instead of being cluttered into one. That being said some of the things you would think would be easy become complicated with activity based tabs. Its hard to pass information between tabs without creating overhead. Activity based tabs also use more memory/CPU time as they have the overhead of the activity around each of them. Please consider this and the many more trade offs before diving into using an Activity based TabHost. I know now that I would personally go with a view based TabHost if I ever used them again.